# Submodules of a Quotient Ring Viewed as a Module

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

I'm aware of the fact that when a commutative ring $R$ is viewed as a module over itself, the submodules of $R$ are just the ideals. We can pick an ideal $I \subset R$ and take the quotient ring $R/I$, which is also an $R$-module. Are the $R$-submodules of $R/I$ again the ideals of $R/I$ as a ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. For any $R/I$-module $M$, the $R/I$-submodules of $M$ coincide with the $R$-submodules of $M$. This is because an $R/I$-module is the same thing as an $R$-module killed by $I$ (the $R/I$-module structure is uniquely determined by the $R$-module structure).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm more interested in the submodules of $R/I$ as an $R$-module.

Comment: A subset of $R/I$, or of any $R/I$-module, is an $R/I$-submodule if and only if it is an $R$-submodule. Since the $R/I$-submodules of $R/I$ are just the ideals, these are also the $R$-submodules. My answer addresses this.

Comment: Oh I see now, my mistake.